# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header value not equal to the supplied origin, POST method

Tags: rest, post, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I get the following message in the Chrome dev tools console when submitting a contact form *(making a POST request)* on the /about.html section my portfolio web site:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://123abc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/contact' from origin 'https://example.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://example.net/' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

I don't know how to troubleshoot this properly, any help is appreciated.Essentially, this is happening (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSAllowOriginNotMatchingOrigin) and I don't know where within my AWS assets to fix it. This person had same problem, but i'm unsure of how to apply their fix ([CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match... but it does‼](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303654/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-does-not-match-but-it-does))

Here is a description of the AWS stack:

1. **Context**, I am using an S3 bucket as static website using CloudFront and Route 53, this stuff works fine, has for years. When I added the form, I did the following to allow the HTTP POST request:
2. **Cloudfront**, On the site's distribution I added a behavior with all settings default except:

- Path pattern: /contact (I am using this bc this is the API Gateway resource path ending)
- Origin and origin groups: S3-Website-example.net.s3-website... (Selected correct origin)
- Viewer protocol policy: HTTP and HTTPS
- Allowed HTTP methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE

> Cache HTTP methods GET and HEAD methods are cached by default: Checked OPTIONS box

- Origin request policy - optional: CORS-S3Origin
- Response headers policy - optional: CORS-With-Preflight

3. **API Gateway**, Created a REST API with all default settings except:

- Created a resource: /contact
- Created a method: POST
- For /contact, Resource Actions > Enable CORS:

> - Methods: OPTIONS and POST both checked
> - Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'https://example.net' (no ending slash)
> - Clicked "Enable CORS and Replace existing headers"
> - Results are all checked green:
>   ✔ Add Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin Method Response Headers to OPTIONS method
>   ✔ Add Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin Integration Response Header Mappings to OPTIONS method
>   ✔ Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin Method Response Header to POST method
>   ✔ Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin Integration Response Header Mapping to POST method

- Created a stage called "prod", ensured it had the /contact resource, and deployed.
- At the /contact - POST - Method Execution, The test works as expected (triggers Lambda func that uses SES to send email, which I do actually receive).
  *The only thing I feel unsure about with API Gateway is after I enable the CORS, I can't seem to find a place where that setting has been saved, and if I click again on enable CORS, it is back to the default form ( with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*')*

4. **Amazon SES**, set up 2 verified identities for sending/receiving emails via lamda.
5. **Lamda**, set up a basic javascript function with default settings, the REST API is listed as a trigger, and does actually work as previously mentioned. The function code is:

   ```js
   var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
   var ses = new AWS.SES({ region: "us-east-1" });
   var RECEIVER = 'myemail@email.com';
   var SENDER = 'me@example.net';
   var response = {
       "statusCode": 200,
       "headers": {
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
       },
       "isBase64Encoded": false,
       "body": "{ \"result\": \"Success\"\n}"
   }
   exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
       console.log('Received event:', event);
       var params = {
           Destination: {
               ToAddresses: [
                   RECEIVER
               ]
           },
           Message: {
               Body: {
                   Text: {
                       Data: 'first name: ' + event.fname + 'last name: ' + event.lname + '\nemail: ' + event.email + '\nmessage: ' + event.message,
                       Charset: 'UTF-8'
                   }
               },
               Subject: {
                   Data: 'Website Query Form: ' + event.name,
                   Charset: 'UTF-8'
               }
           },
           Source: SENDER
       };
       return ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
   };
   ```

   *The only thing i can think of here is to maybe update the response to have "headers": {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://example.net"}*

   **S3** bucket that holds the site contents, in permissions > CORS, I have the following JSON to allow a post of the contact form (notice no slash):

   ```json
   [
       {
           "AllowedHeaders": [
               "*"
           ],
           "AllowedMethods": [
               "POST"
           ],
           "AllowedOrigins": [
               "https://example.net"
           ],
           "ExposeHeaders": []
       }
   ]
   ```
6. **Permissions/Roles**, Established Roles and permissions per

- AWS guide:  create dynamic contact forms for s3 static websites using aws lambda amazon api gateway and amazon ses
- video titled: "Webinar: Dynamic Contact Forms for S3 Static Websites Using AWS Lambda, API Gateway & Amazon SES"

7. **Client code**, this is a very milk toast function being called to post the form on click.

   ```js
   function submitToAPI(event) {

       event.preventDefault();

       URL = "https://123abc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/contact";

       const namere = /[A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z]/;
       const emailre = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,6})?$/;

       let fname = document.getElementById('first-name-input').value;
       let lname = document.getElementById('last-name-input').value;
       let email = document.getElementById('email-input').value;
       let message = document.getElementById('message-input').value;

       console.log(`first name: ${fname}, last name: ${lname}, email: ${email}\nmessage: ${message}`);

       if (!namere.test(fname) || !namere.test(lname)) {
           alert ("Name can not be less than 2 characters");
           return;
       }

       if (email == "" || !emailre.test(email)) {
           alert ("Please enter valid email address");
           return;
       }

       if (message == "") {
           alert ("Please enter a message");
           return;
       }

       let data = {
           fname : fname,
           lname: lname,
           email : email,
           message : message
           };

       $.ajax(
           {
           type: "POST",
           url : URL,
           dataType: "json",
           crossDomain: "true",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: JSON.stringify(data),
           success: function () {
               alert("Successful");
               document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
               location.reload();
           },
           error: function () {
               alert("Unsuccessful");
           }
       });
   }
   ```

[image: Console logged CORS errors]

[image: POST]

[image: OPTIONS]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow/70375725#70375725

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the response in the lambda function had "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" set to "*".

This should have been set to the exact origin (no trailing slash), so if the origin is 'https://example.net', then the response in the lamda function should have "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" set to 'https://example.net' as shown below:

````js
var response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://example.net"
    },
    "isBase64Encoded": false,
    "body": "{ \"result\": \"Success\"\n}"
}```
````